# `UITableView` extra space at the top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I don't remember seeing this extra space when adding `UITableView`s to my scenes. This happened when I dragged the default object from the object library in Interface Builder.

To highlight the gap, I've changed the background color for the table to grey.

[image]

I fill the table with data with the following code.

```
extension UserListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

And I set the `dataSource` for the outline inside my `viewDidLoad` of the view controller.

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

So where does this gap come from? And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set this in your controller :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

This property is quite self explanatory. With in iOS 7, Apple introduced a translucent top bar. Usually they expect that your UITableview starts from the top like some part is behind the top bar. In this case it is useful to have an automatic inset at the top so that the content is visible.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the added explanation. Will accept asap.

Answer (score 13):

You can also deselect it directly from the Attribute inspector of your UIViewController in the StoryBoard, so you don't add code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the tableView is inside a tableViewContorller and the table view is static,then change the style of the tableView cells from "Grouped" to "Plain".This would remove extra space at the top of the table view cells.